# host ssh key for gitlab container

Tags: docker, ssh-keys, gitlab-omnibus

I am running gitlab/gitlab-ce on rancheros. When I replace a container with a new one, I got error
"ECDSA host key for [host] has changed and you have requested strict checking."

I known I can remove the old key from known_host and make it work.

My question is:
Is there a way to preserve the host keys for the server? And where are those keys stored inside container?

Following solutions won't work.
Copied over old keys inside docker /etc/ssh/*
configs, logs and data folder are mounted from volume.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to your `ssh` command:

```
-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

to disable strict checking

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know I can resolve this from client side. But I am really looking for a server side resolution. Say (very unlikely), I got a MITM attack. Without the check, I won't even know it.